# versionone: get defects with project and change date filter from version one java sdk

Tags: java, api, rest, sdk, versionone

I am looking to retrieve list of all defects that belongs to project A and that have modified in last 24 hours. I used the given below code to retrieve list of all defects that belongs to project(project is a string variable containing name of the project)

```
        scope=defectType.getAttributeDefinition("Scope.Name");
        FilterTerm toDoTerm = Query.term(scope);
        toDoTerm.Equal(project);
```

Now i want to add one more condition, list only those defects that have been changed in last 24 hours.
I checked the versionone api but could not find any relevant java source code/example or function name.

How can i add conditions like "and" or "or" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GroupFilterTerm to concatenate filters (And or Or) like this:

```
FilterTerm toDoTerm = new FilterTerm(nameAttribute);
toDoTerm.equal(project);
FilterTerm dateFilter = new FilterTerm(dateAttribute);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
dateFilter.lessOrEqual(c.getTime());

GroupFilterTerm groupFilter = new AndFilterTerm(toDoTerm, dateFilter);
Collection<IAttributeDefinition> attributesToQuery = new LinkedList<IAttributeDefinition>();
attributesToQuery.add(nameAttribute);
attributesToQuery.add(dateAttribute);
query = new Query(storyAsset.getOid().getMomentless(), true);
query.getSelection().addAll(attributesToQuery);
query.setFilter(groupFilter);
```

In this example I am querying Defects that are in a specific project, and where the Defect ChangeDate (dateAttribute) value is less than or equal to today.

You´ll need to take into account how Java handles Date variables when you do the comparison.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, Is there exist some good document that have explained query in object oriented model(Java)

Comment: I could not even find description about FilterTerm on version site. Could you please tell if there exist any such good document.

Comment: Some documentation can be found in the GitHub repo for the Java.SDK.

**Main Repo**: https://github.com/versionone/VersionOne.SDK.Java.APIClient  
**General docs**: http://versionone.github.io/VersionOne.SDK.Java.APIClient/introduction.html  
**JavaDocs**: http://versionone.github.io/VersionOne.SDK.Java.APIClient/apidocs/index.html

The JavaDocs contains information about all the classes and methods in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks @acey.bunch I wish apidocs could be more detailed. I also found one more link while searching for groupFilter i.e http://legacy.community.versionone.com/sdk/DetailedDocumentation/SDK%20Java/api/index.html but it gives following error "Cannot connect to the configuration database."

Comment: Hi @vplechuc , Right now i am fetching changedate attribute as defectType.getAttributeDefinition("ChangeDate"); , It gives me date in this format : "Fri May 25 07:38:37 IST 2012", I tried to run the above code. The above code run successfully with integer fields but date field is giving me error. Could you please tell me how can i compare date.